# Latex-suite <alt-I> mapping

Tags: filetype-tex, linux, plugin-vim-latex, linux-ubuntu

Last week I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop. During my last installation of ubuntu (also 18.04) I learned vim and used it in combination with the latex-suite. However on this new installation the `<alt-I>` function does not work.

The `<alt>` key works fine, for example with `<alt-L>` and `<alt-C>`, but when I use `<alt-I>` I get **é** in both gVim and vi in the gnome terminal.

I reused a part of my .vimrc of my previous installation. From what I understood, this is the part that handles the alt-key mapping:

```
   let c='a'
   while c <= 'z'
     exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
     exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
     let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
   endw

   set timeout ttimeoutlen=50
```

(I think that I found this here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130389/vim-latex-suite-alt-macro-not-working but I am not sure since this is from my old .vimrc file, from my old installation.)

Because the alt-key works (for the other key combinations), I expect that it is some other setting.

Vim-latex is installed using Vundle. I tried to put this line:`let g:Tex_AdvancedMath = 1` in `~/.vim/bundle/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim`. I tried both methods:

```
" LaTeX filetype
"     Language: LaTeX (ft=tex)
"   Maintainer: Srinath Avadhanula
"        Email: srinath@fastmail.fm

if !exists('s:initLatexSuite')
    let s:initLatexSuite = 1
    exec 'so '.expand('<sfile>:p:h').'/latex-suite/main.vim'
    let g:Tex_AdvancedMath = 1
    silent! do LatexSuite User LatexSuiteInitPost
endif

silent! do LatexSuite User LatexSuiteFileType
```

*and:*

```
" LaTeX filetype
"     Language: LaTeX (ft=tex)
"   Maintainer: Srinath Avadhanula
"        Email: srinath@fastmail.fm

if !exists('s:initLatexSuite')
    let s:initLatexSuite = 1
    exec 'so '.expand('<sfile>:p:h').'/latex-suite/main.vim'

    silent! do LatexSuite User LatexSuiteInitPost
endif

silent! do LatexSuite User LatexSuiteFileType
let g:Tex_AdvancedMath = 1
```

(The difference between both methods is that either the `let g:Tex_AdvancedMath = 1` is inside or outside the if statement).

Nothing worked so far. I did not had any trouble with the `<alt>`-key, like that it is linked to the menu in GVim for example.

To be complete, this is my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX'
Plugin 'junegunn/goyo.vim' 
Plugin 'junegunn/limelight.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold' "fold
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

set relativenumber
syntax on
set showmatch
set ruler
set smarttab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

set expandtab

set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
map <f2> :w<cr><leader>ll
"set spell spelllang=en_us
set spell spelllang=en

let c='a'
while c <= 'z'
  exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
  exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
  let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
endw

set timeout ttimeoutlen=50

" Use a blinking upright bar cursor in Insert mode, a blinking block in normal
if &term == 'xterm-256color' || &term == 'screen-256color'
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[5 q"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[1 q"
endif

if exists('$TMUX')
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
endif
```

**edit**

I disabled my .vimrc, by renaming *.vimrc* → *.vimrc_backup*. Now the plugins are disabled, but I é is still the result from clicking `<alt-i>` in GVim, but not in the terminal.

Comment: `<alt-i>` and `é` are the same thing for gvim (I can't tell for Vim as I've given up on it because of alt key). There is an old issue in vim-latex where French users cannot properly type `é`. Because of that, there is a FAQ entry in vim-latex that explains how to avoid mapping `<alt-i>`. Could it be that the _trick_ is activated in your configuration, or that may be vim-latex finally gave up on `alt-i`? http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/faq.shtml#faq-e-acute

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First I wanted to mention that this happens only in vim, not in another editor/terminal/browser. But I looked at your answer and now I tried to map `<alt-i>` to tex_InsertItemOnThisLine. This worked, but now that text is shown when I used `<alt-i>`, and I expect that some function should be called? Another problem is that most guides talk about tex.vim file, but I do not have that file. Is it possible that a Vundle installation is not the correct way to install the latex-suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to remove the plugin from Vundle and manually add all the files in my .vim folder ([as described here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download)).

Then I added the line `imap <buffer> <m-i> <Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine` in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim`. Now `<alt-i>` inserted an item, instead of the text *Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine*. So I think there was a problem with the combination of Vundle and the latex-suite.